# 'Overflow: hidden/auto;' not correcting page border issues with floating elements

Tags: html, css

I started self-teaching web development about six months ago & I'm creating a mock-up website I don't intend to publish for practice purposes. My problem is that I'm attempting to add a page border but I have two floating elements - the navbar (left) and the main content (right) and this is causing a problem with the page border.

After researching recommendations on Stack Overflow and elsewhere, I'm using 'Overflow: Hidden' (I've also tried 'Auto') but this hasn't corrected the problem. The page border is still stuck to the top of the document.

See screenshot here:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Learn!ng Java$cr!pt ©</title>
    <style>
#bodyid {
  width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "trebuchet ms", garamond, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  border: 6px double black;
  padding: 20px;
}

main {
  float: right;
  width: 800px;
  overflow: auto; /* This is not correcting the page border issues with floating elements */
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto; /* This is not correcting the page border issues with floating elements */
}

nav form {
  margin: 5px 20px 10px 0px;
}

#searchnav {
  width: 114px;
  font-family: "trebuchet ms", garamond, serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#submitnav {
  /* NOTE: The following top two elements allow for the exact positioning of the button next to the input element */
  position: relative; /* NOTE: Relative to original position */
  right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform;
}

#submitnav:hover {
  background-color: #CCC;
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}

.navbar {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px #0000E1;
  margin: 5px 20px 10px 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: opacity 0.7s, transform 1.1s;
}

.navbar:hover {
  opacity: 0.30;
  transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #A80000;
  text-shadow: 10px 10px 10px grey;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

header h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #A80000;
  text-shadow: 10px 10px 10px grey;
}

#headerimg {

}

section h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: initial;
}

section p {
  text-align: justify;
}

#form1 {
  text-align: initial;
}

fieldset {

}

legend h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
}

#disclaimer {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 10px;
}

footer {
  font-size: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.boxdiv {
  border: 3px double black;
}

.boxdiv2 {
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
    </style>
    <script>
// Add code here
    </script>
  </head>
  <body id="bodyid">
    <nav>
      <form id="formnav">
        <input name="search" type="text" id="searchnav" placeholder="Search...">
        <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitnav">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <a id="homenav" class="navbar" href="#bodyid">Home</a>
      <a id="aboutnav" class="navbar" href="#aboutsec">About</a>
      <a id="discnav" class="navbar" href="#disclaimer">Disclaimer</a>
      <a id="contactnav" class="navbar" href="#form1">Contact</a>
      <a id="intronav" class="navbar" href="#introsec">Introduction to JS</a>
      <a id="dtnav" class="navbar" href="#dtsec">Data Types</a>
      <a id="varnav" class="navbar" href="#varsec">Variables</a>
      <a id="candlnav" class="navbar" href="#candlsec">Comparison & Logical Operators</a>
      <a id="functnav" class="navbar" href="#functsec">Functions</a>
      <a id="oandanav" class="navbar" href="#oandasec">Objects & Arrays</a>
      <a id="dandlnav" class="navbar" href="#dandlsec">Decisions & Loops</a>
    </nav>

    <main>
    <header>
      <h1>Learn!ng Java$cr!pt ©</h1>
      <h2>Getting to grips with the basic structure & functionality of JavaScript</h2>
      <img id="headerimg" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guiguan/autocomplete-javascript/master/images/javascript.png">
    </header>

      <div class="boxdiv"></div>

      <article>
        <section id="aboutsec">
          <h3>What is <em>Learn!ng Java$cr!pt ©</em> ?</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras molestie eget ante vitae posuere. Etiam varius mauris lobortis dolor consequat ultricies. Vestibulum dignissim leo in luctus ornare. Donec venenatis nunc ac arcu dapibus pretium. Morbi in nibh tristique, tempus ipsum pulvinar, egestas dolor. Ut aliquam lorem eget ipsum ullamcorper malesuada. Donec nisl ex, mollis sed auctor eu, pharetra et massa. Mauris a purus odio. In dolor tellus, suscipit nec accumsan et, accumsan sed augue. Pellentesque commodo eget nisl in iaculis.</p>
          <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque ultricies, lorem sed egestas pulvinar, ipsum elit semper urna, nec tincidunt dolor elit ultrices urna. Aliquam convallis semper nunc, cursus dictum tellus rutrum nec. Nulla arcu ligula, commodo et vestibulum fermentum, pulvinar quis est. Sed ultricies, odio a ornare porta, velit tellus luctus lacus, ornare blandit leo magna id odio. Phasellus egestas venenatis libero, quis imperdiet sapien ullamcorper consequat. Etiam dapibus laoreet cursus. Sed lacinia neque mauris, eu pulvinar elit blandit at. Donec ac mollis libero. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris nulla lacus, tincidunt sed egestas vel, imperdiet sed eros. Curabitur fermentum enim ut orci dapibus interdum. Nullam suscipit nulla arcu, vel egestas ligula aliquam eu.</p>
        </section>

        <div class="boxdiv"></div>

        <section id="introsec">
          <h3>Introduction: What is JavaScript?</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras molestie eget ante vitae posuere. Etiam varius mauris lobortis dolor consequat ultricies. Vestibulum dignissim leo in luctus ornare. Donec venenatis nunc ac arcu dapibus pretium. Morbi in nibh tristique, tempus ipsum pulvinar, egestas dolor. Ut aliquam lorem eget ipsum ullamcorper malesuada. Donec nisl ex, mollis sed auctor eu, pharetra et massa. Mauris a purus odio. In dolor tellus, suscipit nec accumsan et, accumsan sed augue. Pellentesque commodo eget nisl in iaculis.</p>
          <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque ultricies, lorem sed egestas pulvinar, ipsum elit semper urna, nec tincidunt dolor elit ultrices urna. Aliquam convallis semper nunc, cursus dictum tellus rutrum nec. Nulla arcu ligula, commodo et vestibulum fermentum, pulvinar quis est. Sed ultricies, odio a ornare porta, velit tellus luctus lacus, ornare blandit leo magna id odio. Phasellus egestas venenatis libero, quis imperdiet sapien ullamcorper consequat. Etiam dapibus laoreet cursus. Sed lacinia neque mauris, eu pulvinar elit blandit at. Donec ac mollis libero. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris nulla lacus, tincidunt sed egestas vel, imperdiet sed eros. Curabitur fermentum enim ut orci dapibus interdum. Nullam suscipit nulla arcu, vel egestas ligula aliquam eu.</p>
        </section>

        <div class="boxdiv"></div>

        <section id="dtsec">
          <h3>Data Types</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras molestie eget ante vitae posuere. Etiam varius mauris lobortis dolor consequat ultricies. Vestibulum dignissim leo in luctus ornare. Donec venenatis nunc ac arcu dapibus pretium. Morbi in nibh tristique, tempus ipsum pulvinar, egestas dolor. Ut aliquam lorem eget ipsum ullamcorper malesuada. Donec nisl ex, mollis sed auctor eu, pharetra et massa. Mauris a purus odio. In dolor tellus, suscipit nec accumsan et, accumsan sed augue. Pellentesque commodo eget nisl in iaculis.</p>
          <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque ultricies, lorem sed egestas pulvinar, ipsum elit semper urna, nec tincidunt dolor elit ultrices urna. Aliquam convallis semper nunc, cursus dictum tellus rutrum nec. Nulla arcu ligula, commodo et vestibulum fermentum, pulvinar quis est. Sed ultricies, odio a ornare porta, velit tellus luctus lacus, ornare blandit leo magna id odio. Phasellus egestas venenatis libero, quis imperdiet sapien ullamcorper consequat. Etiam dapibus laoreet cursus. Sed lacinia neque mauris, eu pulvinar elit blandit at. Donec ac mollis libero. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris nulla lacus, tincidunt sed egestas vel, imperdiet sed eros. Curabitur fermentum enim ut orci dapibus interdum. Nullam suscipit nulla arcu, vel egestas ligula aliquam eu.</p>
        </section>

        <div class="boxdiv"></div>

        <section id="varsec">
          <h3>Variables</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras molestie eget ante vitae posuere. Etiam varius mauris lobortis dolor consequat ultricies. Vestibulum dignissim leo in luctus ornare. Donec venenatis nunc ac arcu dapibus pretium. Morbi in nibh tristique, tempus ipsum pulvinar, egestas dolor. Ut aliquam lorem eget ipsum ullamcorper malesuada. Donec nisl ex, mollis sed auctor eu, pharetra et massa. Mauris a purus odio. In dolor tellus, suscipit nec accumsan et, accumsan sed augue. Pellentesque commodo eget nisl in iaculis.</p>
          <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque ultricies, lorem sed egestas pulvinar, ipsum elit semper urna, nec tincidunt dolor elit ultrices urna. Aliquam convallis semper nunc, cursus dictum tellus rutrum nec. Nulla arcu ligula, commodo et vestibulum fermentum, pulvinar quis est. Sed ultricies, odio a ornare porta, velit tellus luctus lacus, ornare blandit leo magna id odio. Phasellus egestas venenatis libero, quis imperdiet sapien ullamcorper consequat. Etiam dapibus laoreet cursus. Sed lacinia neque mauris, eu pulvinar elit blandit at. Donec ac mollis libero. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris nulla lacus, tincidunt sed egestas vel, imperdiet sed eros. Curabitur fermentum enim ut orci dapibus interdum. Nullam suscipit nulla arcu, vel egestas ligula aliquam eu.</p>
        </section>

        <div class="boxdiv"></div>

        <section id="candlsec">
          <h3>Comparison & Logical Operators</h3>
          <!-- NOTE: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp -->
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras molestie eget ante vitae posuere. Etiam varius mauris lobortis dolor consequat ultricies. Vestibulum dignissim leo in luctus ornare. Donec venenatis nunc ac arcu dapibus pretium. Morbi in nibh tristique, tempus ipsum pulvinar, egestas dolor. Ut aliquam lorem eget ipsum ullamcorper malesuada. Donec nisl ex, mollis sed auctor eu, pharetra et massa. Mauris a purus odio. In dolor tellus, suscipit nec accumsan et, accumsan sed augue. Pellentesque commodo eget nisl in iaculis.</p>
          <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque ultricies, lorem sed egestas pulvinar, ipsum elit semper urna, nec tincidunt dolor elit ultrices urna. Aliquam convallis semper nunc, cursus dictum tellus rutrum nec. Nulla arcu ligula, commodo et vestibulum fermentum, pulvinar quis est. Sed ultricies, odio a ornare porta, velit tellus luctus lacus, ornare blandit leo magna id odio. Phasellus egestas venenatis libero, quis imperdiet sapien ullamcorper consequat. Etiam dapibus laoreet cursus. Sed lacinia neque mauris, eu pulvinar elit blandit at. Donec ac mollis libero. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris nulla lacus, tincidunt sed egestas vel, imperdiet sed eros. Curabitur fermentum enim ut orci dapibus interdum. Nullam suscipit nulla arcu, vel egestas ligula aliquam eu.</p>
        </section>

        <div class="boxdiv"></div>

        <section id="functsec">
          <h3>Functions</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras molestie eget ante vitae posuere. Etiam varius mauris lobortis dolor consequat ultricies. Vestibulum dignissim leo in luctus ornare. Donec venenatis nunc ac arcu dapibus pretium. Morbi in nibh tristique, tempus ipsum pulvinar, egestas dolor. Ut aliquam lorem eget ipsum ullamcorper malesuada. Donec nisl ex, mollis sed auctor eu, pharetra et massa. Mauris a purus odio. In dolor tellus, suscipit nec accumsan et, accumsan sed augue. Pellentesque commodo eget nisl in iaculis.</p>
          <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque ultricies, lorem sed egestas pulvinar, ipsum elit semper urna, nec tincidunt dolor elit ultrices urna. Aliquam convallis semper nunc, cursus dictum tellus rutrum nec. Nulla arcu ligula, commodo et vestibulum fermentum, pulvinar quis est. Sed ultricies, odio a ornare porta, velit tellus luctus lacus, ornare blandit leo magna id odio. Phasellus egestas venenatis libero, quis imperdiet sapien ullamcorper consequat. Etiam dapibus laoreet cursus. Sed lacinia neque mauris, eu pulvinar elit blandit at. Donec ac mollis libero. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris nulla lacus, tincidunt sed egestas vel, imperdiet sed eros. Curabitur fermentum enim ut orci dapibus interdum. Nullam suscipit nulla arcu, vel egestas ligula aliquam eu.</p>
        </section>

        <div class="boxdiv"></div>

        <section id="oandasec">
          <h3>Objects & Arrays</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras molestie eget ante vitae posuere. Etiam varius mauris lobortis dolor consequat ultricies. Vestibulum dignissim leo in luctus ornare. Donec venenatis nunc ac arcu dapibus pretium. Morbi in nibh tristique, tempus ipsum pulvinar, egestas dolor. Ut aliquam lorem eget ipsum ullamcorper malesuada. Donec nisl ex, mollis sed auctor eu, pharetra et massa. Mauris a purus odio. In dolor tellus, suscipit nec accumsan et, accumsan sed augue. Pellentesque commodo eget nisl in iaculis.</p>
          <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque ultricies, lorem sed egestas pulvinar, ipsum elit semper urna, nec tincidunt dolor elit ultrices urna. Aliquam convallis semper nunc, cursus dictum tellus rutrum nec. Nulla arcu ligula, commodo et vestibulum fermentum, pulvinar quis est. Sed ultricies, odio a ornare porta, velit tellus luctus lacus, ornare blandit leo magna id odio. Phasellus egestas venenatis libero, quis imperdiet sapien ullamcorper consequat. Etiam dapibus laoreet cursus. Sed lacinia neque mauris, eu pulvinar elit blandit at. Donec ac mollis libero. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris nulla lacus, tincidunt sed egestas vel, imperdiet sed eros. Curabitur fermentum enim ut orci dapibus interdum. Nullam suscipit nulla arcu, vel egestas ligula aliquam eu.</p>
        </section>

        <div class="boxdiv"></div>

        <section id="dandlsec">
          <h3>Decisions & Loops</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras molestie eget ante vitae posuere. Etiam varius mauris lobortis dolor consequat ultricies. Vestibulum dignissim leo in luctus ornare. Donec venenatis nunc ac arcu dapibus pretium. Morbi in nibh tristique, tempus ipsum pulvinar, egestas dolor. Ut aliquam lorem eget ipsum ullamcorper malesuada. Donec nisl ex, mollis sed auctor eu, pharetra et massa. Mauris a purus odio. In dolor tellus, suscipit nec accumsan et, accumsan sed augue. Pellentesque commodo eget nisl in iaculis.</p>
          <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque ultricies, lorem sed egestas pulvinar, ipsum elit semper urna, nec tincidunt dolor elit ultrices urna. Aliquam convallis semper nunc, cursus dictum tellus rutrum nec. Nulla arcu ligula, commodo et vestibulum fermentum, pulvinar quis est. Sed ultricies, odio a ornare porta, velit tellus luctus lacus, ornare blandit leo magna id odio. Phasellus egestas venenatis libero, quis imperdiet sapien ullamcorper consequat. Etiam dapibus laoreet cursus. Sed lacinia neque mauris, eu pulvinar elit blandit at. Donec ac mollis libero. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris nulla lacus, tincidunt sed egestas vel, imperdiet sed eros. Curabitur fermentum enim ut orci dapibus interdum. Nullam suscipit nulla arcu, vel egestas ligula aliquam eu.</p>
        </section>
      </article>

      <div class="boxdiv"></div>

      <form id="form1">
        <!-- NOTE: Refer to 'JavaScript Exp Doc' for guidance -->
        <fieldset>
          <legend><h3>Contact Form</h3></legend>
        </fieldset>
      </form>

      <div id="disclaimer">
        <p><strong>Disclaimer:</strong> The links we have provided on this website are external websites created by third parties. We therefore cannot take responsibility for any issues that you may or may not encounter when directed to external content. We also claim no credit for the creation and maintenance of the material provided on third party websites.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="boxdiv2"></div>

      <footer>
      <span>Mathew J. M. | 2019 ©</span>
      <span>Last Updated: 11<sup>th</sup> February 2019</span>
    </footer>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the `clearfix method`.

Comment: its kind of important to see what your html markup looks like since css can vary depending on this structure.

Comment: Thanks Quentin. I used .clearfix::after { content: ""; clear: both; } after the 'body' but it destroyed the vertical navbar and the styling.

Comment: I've just edited my question to include all of the code, Weber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. Without seeing a working example it's a bit difficult to help you. Please try [to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The parent container holding the floated children should have the "`overflow:hidden`" applied to it. There is also another technique where you can use CSS pseudo elements on the parent to clear the floats.

```
.group:before,
.group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.group:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rawnewdlz! I have tried using 'overflow:hidden' on the containing element and and the page border remains the same. I'll try your second solution and let you know how it goes...

Comment: As with the 'clearfix' solution, it solves the page border issue but it destroys the navbar - it's no longer vertical (block-level) and all the other styling has been removed (i.e. text-decoration: none, color, etc).

Comment: As you can see with this screenshot, the page border now looks fine but not without the aforementioned problems with the navbar: http://i63.tinypic.com/2v81r80.png . You can see a screenshot of the original before the changes in my question.

Comment: Did you only add the class of "`group`" to the `<body>`? `<body id="bodyid" class="group">`. It looks okay when testing on your codepen: https://codepen.io/MathewJM/pen/ZworYV

Comment: Using 'nav:before' on its own seems to solve the issue and keeps the navbar styling intact, but now the static, vertical navbar is covering the main content. Before making this change the navbar consisted of 200px/1000px of the document, the 'main' content of 800px/1000px.

Comment: I didn't add a 'group' class to the body, only an ID (for the navbar 'Home' link). The link you posted shows the page border stuck at the top of the document. Some of the solutions work but then create the problems I've mentioned. 

Comment: My apologies for the miscommunication. I meant I used your codepen link and added the class of "`group`" to the body and that didn't appear to have any adverse effects to any other elements.

Comment: I've tried adding 'group' as a class to the 'body' tag and it doesn't solve the page border issue. Thanks for sticking by me on this one anyway, I'd love to find a solution... 

Comment: I cloned your pen and added the class. Does this look okay on your end? https://codepen.io/rawnewdlz/pen/rPvrdy

Comment: That's perfect! I didn't keep the other changes from before, that was the problem. I'll note what you did and keep it in mind in future. Thanks so much, rawnewdlz! 